# My Jquery hiccups on my Menu Drop Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Everything works. However, when clicking on the drop down menu icon, the drop down elements hesitate to slide at first. I obviously want it to have a more fluid transition when sliding.

```
here is my jsfiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0s49o5bz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are setting a `min-height` for several elements, as the `span` and the `ul`. This prevents the animation from being fluent.